# Installing VMWare ESXi 4 on Dell Poweredge T710 Server

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

I want to purchase a Poweredge T710 server to install ESXi 4 on it, and I am not sure about its compatibility.
Can anyone inform me if it is supported?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm... I did this very thing today. What a coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's compatible and supported.

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?device_cat=server&device_id=4095
http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?device_cat=server&device_id=13800

You can browse the full HCL here: http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php.